# Embedded youtube playlist to play in realtime, like a TV channel?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed, live

Currently at early stages of a project, we were wondering if it would be possible for an embedded youtube playlist to be playing on a website as if it were a TV channel, so everyone that visits the site is viewing the same video simultaneously, if you refresh the page you catch up, as if it were live?

```
<iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLFFh4FD8bwkzvxpNVZiFFNj7fYbbuMaa_&autoplay=1&loop=1&mute=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&controls=0"></iframe>
```

This is the iframe code at the moment, and website:

http://rover.live/

Thanks !

Comment: That wont be possible with YouTube videos, I guess, but you could livestream from a PC and record that PC playing the playlist

Comment: Thanks Luca ! Do you know what is happening with youtube letting you embed live videos at the moment? We couldn't get it working and have read that only monetized accounts (1000 subscribers + 4000 watch hours) can now embed live videos ?

Comment: No, I really don't know what is happening there, but you could try other livestreaming services, [Twicht let's you embed a live stream](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/embed/everything/)